# pt-query-digest filter queries with no key or bad key

Tags: mysql, percona

How to filter all queries with either no key or a "bad" key?

```
pt-query-digest /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log --filter '($event->{No_index_used} eq "Yes" || $event->{No_good_index_used} eq "Yes")'
```

This syntax returns evaluation error

Answer (score 1):

I think that [pt-index-usage](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-index-usage.html) is a better tool for what you need. The downside for it is that it needs to run against an active mysql instance, which can cause considerable overhead. If you have a slave that you can use or if you can restore a backup and run it there, it's better to use that.

With pt-query-digest, you can only [filter by a certain set of attributes](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html#attributes-reference)  that are suitable for your input. To see the list of attributes that can be used to filter, you can run something like this:

```
pt-query-digest                \
slowlog                        \
--filter 'print Dumper $event' \
--no-report                    \
--sample 1
```

This will generate a list of pairs such as `Lock_time => '0.000026'`, this means that you can use `$event->{Lock_time}` to filter pt-query-digest results.